# How can I store a vector in a MatLab Map?

Tags: matlab

I want to store a list of strings in the value field of a MatLab Map. Like this:

```
signals('Switch5', ['sig1', 'sig2', 'sig3']);
```

When I do this I get the error `Only one-dimensional indexing supported.` What does this error mean and how can I store a list of values associated with one key?

Comment: You are trying to index into the Map with two indexes, instead you should assign value to a key in the map like : `signals('Switch5') =  {'sig1', 'sig2', 'sig3'}` . Notice that I used a cell array because otherwise sig1 sig2 and sig3 will just get concatenated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use cells:

To initialize:

```
a={'str1','str2','str3'}
b={'str4','str5','str6'}
mapObj=containers.Map({'collection1', 'collection2'},{a,b})

mapObj('collection1')
ans = 
    'str1'    'str2'    'str3'
```

To add a key/value:

```
c={'str7','str8','str9'}
mapObj('collection3')=c
```

Comment: You may want to add the logic of adding additional key/value pairs as well once the map has been created. This only shows how to initialize the `containers.Map`. See the above comment by user Random Guy for more details.